# following parametered script in java is not supported?why?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

i send parametered script to remote gremlin-server, but some scripts are success, some scripts are wrong.

for example, the following testcase is success, and the gremlin server returns the expect result

```
List<Long> ids = Lists.newArrayList(19496288L, 40076200L, 8717992L, 36070256L, 39303024L, 53232552L);
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("ids1", ids);
parameters.put("ret", new String[]{"linkid", "locnwid", "remnwid"});

String strIds = "19496288,40076200,8717992,36070256,39303024,53232552";
String script = String.format("g.V(ids1).outE('L2_LINK').where(otherV().hasId(%s)).valueMap(ret).by(unfold())", strIds)
// this query script is also ok
// String.format("g.V().hasId(ids1).outE('L2_LINK').where(otherV().hasId(%s)).valueMap(ret).by(unfold())", strIds)
client.submit(script, parameters).all().get()
```

but the following testcase is wrong, the gremlin server return nothing

```
List<Long> ids = Lists.newArrayList(19496288L, 40076200L, 8717992L, 36070256L, 39303024L, 53232552L);
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("ids1", ids);
parameters.put("ret", new String[]{"linkid", "locnwid", "remnwid"});

String strIds = "19496288,40076200,8717992,36070256,39303024,53232552";
String script = String.format("g.V(%s).outE('L2_LINK').where(otherV().hasId(ids1)).valueMap(ret).by(unfold())", strIds)

client.submit(script, parameters).all().get()
```

there is any wrong of my second query script? how to fix it?

another question:

i want to query the edges connecting nodes in a group, and the number of nodes exceeds 255, how to construct the query script to getting the edges by searching once?

Answer (score 0):

after many tries, following script can work, but i do not known why.

```
String script = String.format("g.V(ids1).outE('L2_LINK').where(otherV().id().is(within(ids1))).valueMap(ret).by(unfold())", strIds)
```